# Appwidget: Button press on a widget changes TextView's text

Tags: android, android-intent, android-appwidget

I already have a widget app but does not have the exact functionality that I want.

I would like to change the text of the textView that is on the widget by pressing my Roll_a_dice button. How can I do that? This is how my widget looks like:

[image: My widget]

Code for my widget:

```
package com.example.appwidgettest;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;


public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    for(int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++){

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget_layout);

        String timeNow = String.valueOf(MainActivity.throwDice());//"Time: "+ new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.textViewWidget,timeNow);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], views);

    }

}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your call to setTextViewText() should be doing it, it isnt working? logcat error?

Comment: @Nanoc No, text in TextView is not set by Button press

Comment: You are not providing anything to us so we can help you.

Comment: @Nanoc What else do you need?